# Use of も in 一緒に写真を撮ってもいいですか？

Tags: particles, particle-も

I understand the sentence "Can I take a picture with you?" in Japanese overall, but I am a bit confused as for why one can use the particle も in the sentence? What does it do?

Thanks for the help!
C

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the construction ～てもいいです, which expresses permission.

In this case, も isn't the same as the particle も meaning 'also' or 'same'.

Examples:

- 新しくなくてもいいです。it's all right if it's not new/fresh.
- ビールでもいいですか。Will beer do?
- このいすを使ってもいいですか。May I use this chair?

source: Makino S., Tsutsui M.. (2006). A Dictionary Of Basic Japanese Grammar: 日本語基本文法辞典. Tokyo: The Japan Times, page 471-473.

Comment: The way I was taught it is that it is the same も and it expresses 'Even if I take picture, is it ok?'. Not that it's important or we'd ever know how the grammar actually formed, but it might help someone to remember the grammar.